# Excel-Count number of visible cells containing certain string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a sheet in which I first apply a filter to a certain column to show "Unique records only". Now I have a column which contains, for e.g., values like:

```
Applepie
Applesauce
Crabapple
Banana
Mango
```

What I need is the count of all visible cells containing the word "Apple". Note that this should exclude the hidden (filtered out) cells.
Now I have found out a formula:

```
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!A:A,ROW(Sheet1!A:A)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!A:A)),,1))*(Sheet1!A:A="<Text to search>"))`
```

However the problem with this one is this formula searches for the entire text. NOT just a part of it. How do I modify this formula to return count of cells **containing "Apple"** i.e. for this example it should return 3 as the result.

Comment: Do you expect 3 as the result??

Comment: In this case...yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COUNTIF` with wildcards will work alone to count all rows with "Apple" somewhere in the text......but it isn't restricted to visible rows and you can't use `COUNTIF` in conjunction with your `SUBTOTAL` formula.

Adjust your formula like this using `SEARCH` function

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!A:A,ROW(Sheet1!A:A)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!A:A)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",Sheet1!A:A))+0)`

Note: that version may be slow, referencing the whole column - better to restrict the ranges if you can

**Alternative approach**

If you want to avoid that long formula then you could use a helper column to indicate whether each row is filtered or not, e.g. in Sheet1 Z2 use this formula copied down

`=SUBTOTAL(3,A2)`

Now you can use a `COUNTIFS` function to count visible rows containing "Apple"

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*Apple*",Z:Z,1)`

Comment: Finally something that works...thank you sir!
However as you mentioned...it does slow down the process considerably. And I have to reference the whole column as the last row number will always vary. Is there no way to speed things up?

Comment: How much data do you have - you might consider using a dynamic named range....or use the helper column approach - that should be considerably quicker

Comment: ~2000 rows...I will consider the helper column. btw can you please explain dynamic named range.

Comment: A dynamic named range expands automatically as you add data, so you don't have to reference the whole column but the formula will update automatically, so you create a DNR called **data**, for example and use that in your long formula in place of Sheet1!A:A - see here http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic

Comment: ...yet another way would be to convert your data to a table (using INSERT > Table) - tables work a little like DNR's without you having to define the named range - you can refer to a column of the table and that will exopand automatically as you add data

Comment: This sounds good...I'll try it out and see if it helps...thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Marvelous! to fill the gaps, back [in history](https://web.archive.org/web/20100110043824/https://j-walk.com/ss/excel/eee/eee001.txt) giving credits to Laurent Longre that created this Power Formula Technique.

Answer (score 0):

Test: `=COUNTIF(A2:A10;"Apple*")` change `range`

Comment: What I need is the count of all visible cells containing the word "Apple". **Note that this should exclude the hidden (filtered out) cells.**

Comment: STTR beat me to it :D @Gh0sT, you should be able to replace `(Sheet1!A:A="<Text to search>")` with `COUNTIF(A:A,"*apple*")` in the function you already have. You'll need to use `*apple*` rather than `Apple*`, otherwise it'll only count cells that START with Apple

Comment: I did as you said..replaced `(Sheet1!A:A="<Text to search>")` with `COUNTIF(A:A,"*apple*")` but it's showing some garbage value.